# Can you assign functionality to an element multiple times with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an element similar to this:

```
<div class="topics_searcher"></div>
```

And I have JS that looks something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.TopicsSearcher = function () {};

jQuery('.topics_searcher').TopicsSearcher();
```

Now, if I were to issue the following call a second time, will it cause any conflicts?

```
jQuery('.topics_searcher').TopicsSearcher();
```

Comment: It shouldn't, assuming the definition of the `TopicsSearcher` function hasn't changed, though if it changes the content of the element, it could do so again depending on how it works. Hard to tell without knowing what `TopicsSearcher` does.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Fortunately, there is not data/display states that have to be respected if an element is assigned the functionality multiple times. I just wanted to make sure there isn't some deep jQuery/JS conflicts with doing this. ex; if I do jQuery('.element').on('click.......) 2 times, I get 2 responses when the element is clicked.

Comment: What does function do? If it binds events, yes you would bind events multiple times unless you unbind them first or set up ways to test elements (data, class etc)

Comment: Ah, yes. I was starting to think that. Is there a way to test an element to see if it has already been assigned the functionality?